# Defining Variable Within a For Loop

Tags: matlab

I am trying to redefine a variable when an if statement is satisfied in a for loop. Is this not allowed?

```
a = [0,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,0];
[row,col] = size(a);

x0 = -1;
x1 = -1;

for i = 1:row
    for ii = 1:col
        if a(i,ii) ~= 0
            x0 = i;
            break
        end
    end
end

for v = 1:row-1
    for vv = 1:col
        if a(row - v,vv) ~= 0
            x1 = v;
            break
        end
    end
end
```

In this case, x0 and x1 are not overridden. Why?

Comment: Good point @Cris Luengo. I did see this (And should've changed this in the post sooner) already and changed it to a double for loop and the same issue still persists. Please see the updated code in the original post. I know both of the x variables should be assigned 2 since that's where the 1 in matrix a is but it only changes x0 and sets x1 =1.

Comment: That makes sense. When `v=1`, `a(row - v,vv) == a(2,vv)`, which is where the non-zero element is.

Comment: You should step through your program with the debugger, which lets you step line by line, and examine the value of variables at that point in the execution. It is very helpful to understand what is going on in your program.

Comment: True, I just need to look more closely at what's going on since I think I am just losing track. Thank you @Cris Luengo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, when the if statement triggers,
`a(row-v,vv) ~= 0`
is true when v = 1, because row-1 =2, yeilding a(2,2), then your setting v to 1.
I believe in your code, you would want to do

```matlab
for v = 0:row-1
    for vv = 1:col
        if a(row - v,vv) ~= 0
            x1 = row - v;
            break
        end
    end
end
```

Note you also want to change your range on the first line to 0:row-1 so that you hit every line; row-0 would yeild the last array index: 3

Comment: Thanks, yeah I made that indexing change but didn't update my post with it. I knew that Matlab's indexing for matrices start with 1 and not 0 so I assumed that that was also the case for for loop indexing which was an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Woah there not quite, It is the same, your never indexing 0. The reason we use 0:row-1 is because we are taking `row-v`. If we did 1, we would never index the 3rd colom because we would start with row-1 which is the second colom. @Tom

Comment: Ah got it, yeah it's because I wanted to iterate through the matrix backwards and not miss the first(last) row.